# Selecting an element with a class that contains a certain string

Tags: html, xpath, webdriver-io

Say I have this HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        </div class="Something-generated-is7293n">Hello</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How would I go about finding this considering the following constrains:

1. This is for testing purposes so I don't want to assume a certain structure. This way if a `<div>` suddenly is added to the HTML, my xPath won't break my test.
2. I cannot even try to guess what the class will be. I can only know it will contain, say, `Something` and `generated`.

I tried `//div[contains(@class, 'Something') and contains(@class, 'generated')]` with no success at all, which makes me think I'm missing something to have xPath evaluate only *part* of a class.

Of note, my tests use [ChimpJS](https://github.com/xolvio/chimp) with uses [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io/).

Comment: Can you clarify please? Why are you looking for the class name 'menu-bar' if you can't be sure of the class name?

Comment: I'm working with this library: https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules. It will generate unique css classes for me, but there is still some constants in the names generated. Like I said, in `Something-generated-is7293n` I can know for sure `Something` and `generated` will be in it depending on how my React component is named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xpath-fiddle might do the trick for you: http://xpathfiddle.net/UN71EW

Comment: That worked. My previous attempt was pretty much spot on, but it seems like not specifying I wanted a div helped? I don't know, but thank you for your time and answer!

Comment: You're welcome. I think you might be right, that your first attempt indeed was spot on. It works fine here: http://xpathfiddle.net/Z0NRB4